# Identify with CSS or JQUERY whether content of list item begins with a link

Tags: jquery, css

I want to identify whether a list item STARTS with a link - i.e. `<li><a href="...`, as opposed to having a link embedded further within the item like this: `<li>Some text here: <a href="...`. I can't see how to do easily with CSS, so wondering how to achieve with jQuery.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, *why?*

Comment: I want to be able to style the bullet so that any list item that is ALL link will have an arrow bullet, but not when the link is embedded deep within some text, where an arrow bullet might appear misleading. Just a personal preference.

Comment: That's actually possible with CSS, could you share your HTML structure?

Comment: Just a simple listing where I would add a class to the appropriate all-link li tag: `<ul>
 <li>Some text here</li>
 <li><a href="#">A bullet that is ALL link</a></li>
 <li>Some text here, but with a <a href="#">link at the end</a></li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the elements passing the function test. In the test function, the [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) of element incluing text node can be fetched. Here [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) child node can be compared with [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).

```js
var liStartingWithAnchorElement = $('li').filter(function() {
  var first = $(this).contents().first();
  return first.get(0).nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && first.is('a');
});
liStartingWithAnchorElement.addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Some text here: <a href="#">Yahooo</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Yahooo</a>
  </li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here [.get(index)](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get1) is used to get the underlying DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't a great solution for your current situation (as it involves wrapping everything in `<span>` tags, i'm leaving this for future reference. Besides, it's a way of selecting using CSS.

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
}

li > a:first-child:before {
    content: "\25B6";
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    pointer: none;
}

li > span:first-child:before {
    content: "\25CF";
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Some text here:</span><a href="#">Yahooo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Yahooo</span></a></li>
  <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is a pure CSS way of replacing the default list elements with customized list icons, based on the content of the items.

Comment: Thanks - yes, perhaps not ideal as yet - I would probably still need jQuery to manage the spans (bit too much to get client to add them manually), but I may have a go.